# how to pass proc to conditions in validates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, proc

How can I write validation for barcode to be unique for all users where `is_deleted` is false and same chain?

```
validates :barcode, uniqueness: { conditions: -> { |record| where(is_deleted: false, chain_id: record.chain_id) } }, if: proc { |u| u.barcode.present? }
```

what is wrong here?

Thanks.

upd. There can be two users with same barcode with same chain_id, if one of them or both have `:is_deleted => true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates :barcode, uniqueness: { scope: :chain_id, conditions: ->{ where(is_deleted: false) } }, if: proc { |u| u.barcode.present? && u.active? }
```

I came up with a solution. 
Thanks and sorry, its late here and head is not working as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Rails validation have `if` and `unless` parameters which allow you to add conditions, you used it to check barcode presence properly, but you can extend it for `is_deleted` as well.
As to chain id, I understand that you are interested in scoping.

In your case that would be

```
validates :barcode, uniqueness: { scope: [:chain_id] }, if: proc { |u| u.barcode.present? && w.is_deleted.false? }
```